# Are the following two "Swap Vowels in a String" solutions computationally equivalent?

Tags: java, performance, memory, time

I was wondering if the following two solutions for the "Swap the vowels in a string" problem are computationally equivalent (time complexity & memory).

Solution 1 (Main `for` loop with conditional nested `for`) :

```
package practiceQuestions.p1;

    import java.util.HashSet;

    public class Solution {

        public static char[] solve (String text) {
            HashSet vowelSet = new HashSet();
            char[] vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};

            for (char v : vowels) {
                vowelSet.add(v);
            }

            char[] asCharArray = text.toCharArray();
            int lastStop = asCharArray.length;

            for (int i = 0; i < lastStop; i++) {
                if(vowelSet.contains(asCharArray[i])) {
                    for (int j = lastStop - 1; j > i; j--) {
                        if(vowelSet.contains(asCharArray[j])) {
                            char temp = asCharArray[j];
                            asCharArray[j] = asCharArray[i];
                            asCharArray[i] = temp;

                            lastStop = j;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return asCharArray;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String someText = "swap my vowels";
            System.out.println(Solution.solve(someText));
        }

    }
```

Solution 2 (I don't have the code, but here is the explanation) :

There is a main `while` loop which starts from both ends of the string and stores all vowels in a `hashmap` with an integer as the key and the character as the value. Then, based on the position (key) of each value, the function will then swap all vowel characters (value).

Are the two mentioned above computationally equivalent? I know for sure that Solution 2 is more tasking on memory, but I'm not sure about time complexity. I'm guessing Solution 1 is slightly faster.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This isn't going to be terribly rigorous, but I believe it should hold.
Where n is the length of your input string, and we're considering the worst case where the entire string is vowels...

Method 1
Time: n*(time to swap) + constants
Your nested partial loops work out to one complete loop.
Space: n + constants
You are only storing the input string, vowel dictionary, and a few counters/swap variables

Method 2
Time: n*(time to insert in hashmap) + n*(time to find and swap) + constant 
You're doing way more computation in this one than the other one. Instead of a three operation swap, you're computing a hash code and inserting an element. Then afterwards, you do the actual replacement. 
Space: (some multiple of n) + constants
The hash map will take up some amount of extra space for each element in addition to the space required for method 1.

Hope this helps.